# Ip camera stream on WebView not working

Tags: java, android, webview, camera, ip

Hy , i am developing a APP that streams a Ip cam video ,i use another android phone as a Ip cam by running a app called IP Webcam .This app streams the video of the camera into a browser and gives a URL containing the ip of the camera in order to load the URL into the browser and watching the stream .
So that is exacly what my app does ,when i click a search button it loads the URL and shows it on a WebView

My problem : I can watch the  stream on a computer but not in my phone browser , it displays the page right but does not appear the stream

This is how i load the URL when the search button is clicked:

```
    cameraview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.cameraview);

 search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             url = editurl.getText().toString();

            cameraview.loadUrl(url);


        }});
```

Comment: What is the protocol you are using? Hope you are using RTSP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help you with two parts.

1) In AndroidManifest.xml :

- minSdkVersion 19 //The VewView are supported by android 4.4(API level 19) and over.
- targetSdkVersion 19 //   minSdkVersion value(19) and over ---> 19~25

2) url :
   http://yourip:port/videofeed